# How to use script command inside a unix terminal emulator?

Tags: bash, ubuntu, ubuntu-12.04, sh

Here I created a shell script to run another script in terminal and also I need to keep a log file, I knew 'script' command is used to track all user inputs and output. Then how can I use 'script' command in below lines.

```
 #!/bin/bash
 gnome-terminal --full-screen -x ./user_script_file.sh
```

I need to use `script user_screen.log` in above code. Please help me to find a solution,

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
gnome-terminal --full-screen -x script mylogfile.txt -c ./user_script_file.sh
```

-x can take many arguments so there is no need to quote.